# Tried to get data from a form and append it to a global array, but for some reason the data isn't being added

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, forms, debugging

I am trying to get data from a form and append it to a global array but for some reason, the data isn't being added to the array. The code should basically accept the input from the form and store it into the global array. I updated the HTML so you can see the entire syntax. The value should basically be taken from the form and placed into the global array using the "addnew" function.

````
        function addnew()
        {
            //calculateAge();
            //Accept values entered in form
            const fname = document.getElementById('fname').value;
            const mname = document.getElementById('mname').value;
            const lname= document.getElementById('lname').value;
            const dob= document.getElementById('dob').value;
            const genderM = document.getElementsByName('male').checked;
            const genderF = document.getElementsByName('female').checked;
            const age = calculateAge.bYear;
            const bodyType = document.getElementById('Body Type').value;
            const occu= document.getElementById('occu').value;
            const height= document.getElementById('height').value;
            if (fname==null || fname=="")
            {  
                alert();  
            }
            if(mname==null || mname=="")
            {  
                alert();  
            }
            if (lname==null || lname=="")
            {  
                alert();  
            }
            if(dob==null || dob=="")
            {
                alert();
            }
            if (genderM.checked ==  false || genderF.checked == false){  
                alert();   
            }
            if (age <=18 || age >=75)
            {  
                alert();  
            }
            if(height>=170 || height<=200)
            {
                alert();
            }
            if(bodyType==null || bodyType==""){
                alert();
            }
            if(oocu==null || oocu=="")
            {
                alert();
            }
            //Append To array
            
            records.push(fname);
            records.push(mname);
            records.push(lname);
            records.push(dob);
            records.push(genderM);
            records.push(genderF);
            records.push(age);
            records.push(bodyType);
            records.push(occu);
            records.push(height);
            
            
            
            for(i=0;i<records.length;i++)
            {
            console.log(records[i]);
            }
            //showAll();
            //<h1 class="logo"><a href ="index.html"><img src="New folder/logo.jpg" /></a></h1>
            Information.addEventListener('submit', addnew);
        }
    </script>
    ```
````

Comment: What does your HTML look like?

Comment: Are you aware that repeating your sentences can be painful for your readers?

Comment: (I think there's an edit pending to remove the repeated text).

Comment: @benc (maybe, but that doesn't answer my question; PS: and I did not downvote)

Comment: sorry that was an error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

first of all. `name` attribute has nothing to do with `form` element.

second. `Information.addEventListener('submit', addnew);` has no meaning because `Information` is not defined.

and to the core. when submiing a form, the page refreshes defaultly, so the addNew function is aborted like all the other variables. in order to prevent it you have to do as follows.

on submit button ad an id attribute:

```
<button id="submit" type="submit"> Submit </button>
```

then on top of your JS, get the button element and add an event listener to it:

```
let submit = document.getElementById('submit');
submit.addEventListener('click', addnew );
```

and here is the final step. on the addNew function, add an event argument. and on the begining of the function's code, fire the preventDefault method:

```
function addnew(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  // the rest of the code here
}
```

by the way. you have a typo here. it should be `occu`.

```
if (oocu == null || oocu == "") {
  alert();
}
```

good luck!

Comment: removing the addEvent listener outside of the code didn't work. I updated the post to show the entire syntax.

Comment: Tried it, still having the same issue

Comment: Are you getting anything on the console?

Comment: no nothing. `var submit = document.getElementById('submit');
   if(submit){
   submit.addEventListener('click', addnew, false);
   }` had to add this statement because the addeventlistener couldn't be read

Comment: Did you add an id attribute with value 'submit' to the relevant button?

Comment: yes I did everything, the only thing different I added was the if statement above

Comment: wrap your JS code  with this fonction `(window.onload = () => { your JS code here })()`

Comment: code is working now. Thank you so much. what did that piece of code do, if you don't mine explaining?

Comment: If the JS code is placed - like you did - in the `head`, it is executed before the HTML is rendered. So the JS do not find any elements to manipulate - in our case the 'submit' element we refer to - and it says in the console `can not addEventListener of null` etc. The solution is to delay executing the JS until the page was loaded. And this is what the `window.onload` function is doing.